# I am trying to pass a different argument to a function for every schedule such as the following,

Tags: python, arrays, web-scraping, parameter-passing, schedule

```
import schedule
import time

arr = ['React', 'Python', 'JS', 'PHP', 'anything']
def add_no(key):
    return print(key, ' got it')

for i, index in enumerate(arr):
    schedule.every(3).seconds.do(add_no, index)
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(2)
    print(i, ':', index)
```

I am trying to pass a different argument to a function for every schedule such as the following:
every specified period of time I want to pass an argument from the arr and execute code, then when done, I pass the second to the function and so on till the loop exit, like every 3 minutes I want to pass str as an arg to my function and make execution and so on: now the terminal shows,

```
0: React
1: Python
React  got it
2: JS
Python  got it
3: PHP
React  got it
JS  got it   
4: anything
```

what output I want is

```
0: React
React  got it
1: Python
Python  got it
2: JS
JS  got it
3: PHP
PHP got it
JS  got it
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like that

```
import schedule
import time


arr = ['React', 'Python', 'JS', 'PHP', 'anything']


def add_no(key):
    return print(key, ' got it')


for i, index in enumerate(arr):
    schedule.every(3).seconds.do(add_no, index)
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(3)
    print(i, ':', index)
```

```
0 : React
React  got it
1 : Python
Python  got it
React  got it
2 : JS
JS  got it
Python  got it
React  got it
3 : PHP
PHP  got it
JS  got it
Python  got it
React  got it
4 : anything
```